# Garch for covariance matrix?

Tags: volatility, correlation, stochastic-volatility, covariance

I have seen plenty of literature about GARCH on estimation volatility. how about covariance? There are plenty of risk models depending on the covariance matrix.

I guess we can assume the correlation is constant and volatility changes. But in reality in super volatile moment correlation between stocks increases.

Or there is a separate model for estimating correlation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for multivariate GARCH models of which this is an [overview paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.842/pdf).

Multivariate GARCH models have one big drawback: they are pretty hard to estimate due to the number of correlations. This [paper by Caporin and McAleer](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-6419.2011.00683.x/full) might be of interest in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure your question is about having a process for covariance or to have multivariate GARCH.

The standard viewpoint on a stochastic volatility for covariance is to use a **Whishart** process. See for instance
Philipov, A. and M. E. Glickman (2006, July) [Multivariate stochastic volatility via wishart processes.](http://www.hedgefund-index.com/philipov-multivariate.pdf) Journal of Business & Economic Statistics 24 (3), 313-328.
You will find all the formulas.

Just note in dimension one, it is like using a [Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) for your volatility, using a "*time serie*" (a stochastic process) on the parameter $\beta$. I.e.

$$X_t|\sigma^2_t \sim {\cal N}(0, \sigma_t)$$

and

$$\sigma_t^{-2}|\alpha,\beta_t\sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta_t).$$